# PHP Laravel Controller function - how to add a extra condition while importing content from external feed

Tags: php, xml, laravel, if-statement

I am trying to write a function to import data from an external XML feed.

This is the XML feed - https://www.benchmarkintl.com/feed/business_sale_report_businessfeed.xml

Below is the function which will match the application database field with the XML feed field and will import the feed content into the database.

```
public function getBenchmarkXmlFeed() {
        $url= 'https://www.benchmarkintl.com/feed/business_sale_report_businessfeed.xml';

        $arrContextOptions=array(
            "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
            ),
        );

        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
        $xmlString = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $response);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);

        $count = 0;
        foreach ( $xml->business as $business ) {

            $businessObj = Businesses::where(["user_ref" => (string)$business->reference]);
                      
            if( !$businessObj ) {
                $businessObj = new Businesses();
                $businessObj->type = (string)$business->title;
                  
                if( isset($business->keyaspects) ) {
                    $businessObj->extra_description = strip_tags((string)$business->keyaspects);

                }
                                                
                $businessObj->country = "UK";

                $businessObj->save();
                $count++;
            }
        }
        echo $count." new businesses has been send for approval";
    }
```

this function works well

**Problem**

I want to add a condition. This function must only import the business where the country is **UK**. If there is a country that is **not UK** it must skip that content and proceed with the next one.

[image]

How to add that condition in this function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the condition at the beginning of the foreach

```
foreach ( $xml->business as $business ) {
   if($business->country == 'UK') {
      //Import the business
   }
}
```

Comment: what will  be the else condition

Comment: if you only want the UK countries you don't need the else condition